# mismatch between java.lang:type=OperatingSystem and OS

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, jmx

I am trying to monitor open file descriptors created by a java application.
And for that I am looking at attribute `OpenFileDescriptorCount` of an MBean `java.lang:type=OperatingSystem`.

What I observe is that this count and the count arrived at by `lsof -p <java pid> | wc -l` both end up having different numbers.

Any clue why this is so ?